# Recovering underlying Future into Cats' EitherT's Left?

Tags: scala, scala-cats

If I have a `Future[Either[String, Int]]` that represents either a possible error message (`String`) or a successful computation (`Int`), it is simple to move the `Future`'s potential failure into the left side as an error message:

```
def handleFailure(fe: Future[Either[String,Int]]) =
  f.recover({ case e: Exception => Left(s"failed because ${e.getMessage}"))
```

I would expect something similar to exist for `EitherT`, but maybe I just can't find out what it is called. It is relatively simple, but involves unboxing and re-boxing the EitherT which feels kludgey:

```
def handleFailureT(fe: EitherT[Future, String, Int]) =
  EitherT(handleFailure(et.value)) // See above for handleFailure definition
```

Cats did add a `MonadError` instance a [while ago](https://github.com/typelevel/cats/pull/1644), but it's specifically for recovering straight into the Either's `right`, not for replacing the Either itself.

Is `handleFailureT` implemented it Cats, and if so what is it called?

Ideally it would look something like this:

```
class EitherT[F, A, B] {
  def handleFailureT[AA](f: PartialFunction[Throwable, AA]): EitherT[F, AA, B] = EitherT(value.recover(f))
}

// Then used like:
val et: EitherT[Future, String, Int] =
  EitherT(Future(throw new Exception("an error message"))

et.handleFailure {
  case e: Exception => s"Got error with message '${e.message}'"
}
// Now et is Left("Got error with message 'an error message'")
```

Answer (score 3):

It is not at all obvious, but I think this is what `attempt` and `attemptT` are for. For example:

```scala
val myTry: Try[Int] = Try(2)
val myFuture: Future[String] = Future.failed(new Exception())
val myTryET: EitherT[Try, Throwable, Int] = myTry.attemptT
val myFutureET: EitherT[Future, Throwable, String] = myFuture.attemptT

// alternatively
val myFutureET: EitherT[Future, Throwable, String] = EitherT(myFuture.attempt)
```

There was a PR to add this to the documentation: https://github.com/typelevel/cats/pull/3178 -- but it doesn't appear in the documentation currently. However, you can see it here: https://github.com/typelevel/cats/blob/master/docs/src/main/tut/datatypes/eithert.md#from-applicativeerrorf-e-to-eithertf-e-a

Comment: While `attempt` is good and useful, it is not actually what *this* question is about. Attempt converts a `Future` into an `Either`. I'm looking for a method _on EitherT_ that moves the exception from the Future into the EitherT's _left_. The type of such a function would be `(EitherT[Future, A, B], f: Throwable => AA) -> EitherT[Future, AA, B]`. This is admittedly quite specific, so I'm guessing it probably does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

After spending several hours on this I am fairly certain that, as of March 2019, this function is not implemented in cats directly. However, the already existing `catsDataMonadErrorFForEitherT` monad does make it possible to implement it in a *mostly* uncomplicated manner.

```
implicit class EitherTFutureAdditions[A, B](et: EitherT[Future, A, B]) {
  val me = EitherT.catsDataMonadErrorFForEitherT[Future, Throwable, A]

  def recoverLeft(pf: PartialFunction[Throwable, A]): EitherT[Future, A, B] =
    me.recoverWith[B](et) { case t: Throwable =>
      EitherT.fromEither[Future](Left(pf(t)))
    }
}
```

I am uncertain what the performance implications of constructing the monad within the *generic implicit class* are, but it works. If you don't need the generic case, you may want to replace `[A, B]` with explicit types.

While I was at it I also wrote `recoverWithFlat`, `handleErrorLeft`, and `handleErrorWithFlat` and packaged it all into a file `EitherTUtils.scala`

```
// Place this in a new file and then use it like so:
//
//   import EitherTUtils.EitherTFutureAdditions
//
//   val et: EitherT[Future, String, Int] =
//     EitherT(Future.failed[Either[String, Int]](new Exception("example")))
//   et recoverLeft {
//     case e: Exception => s"Failed with reason ${e.getMessage}"
//   }
//
object EitherTUtils {

  /**
    * Convenience additions for recovering and handling Future.failed within an EitherT
    *
    * @see [[cats.ApplicativeError]] for recover, recoverWith, handleError, handleErrorWith, and attemptT
    *
    * @param et a Futured EitherT
    * @tparam A the Either's left type
    * @tparam B the Either's right type
    */
  implicit class EitherTFutureAdditions[A, B](et: EitherT[Future, A, B]) {
    val me = EitherT.catsDataMonadErrorFForEitherT[Future, Throwable, A]

    /**
      * Recover from certain errors from this EitherT's Future (if failed) by mapping them to the EitherT's
      * left value.
      *
      * @see [[recoverWithFlat]] for mapping to an Either[Future, A, B]
      *
      * @see [[handleErrorWithFlat]] to handle any/all errors.
      */
    def recoverLeft(pf: PartialFunction[Throwable, A]): EitherT[Future, A, B] =
      me.recoverWith[B](et) {
        case t: Throwable =>
          EitherT.fromEither[Future](Left(pf(t)))
      }

    /**
      * Recover from certain errors from this EitherT's Future (if failed) by mapping them to the EitherT's
      * value.
      *
      * @see [[recoverLeft]] for mapping to an EitherT's left value.
      *
      * @see [[handleErrorWithFlat]] to handle any/all errors.
      */
    def recoverWithFlat(pf: PartialFunction[Throwable, Either[A, B]]): EitherT[Future, A, B] =
      me.recoverWith[B](et) {
        case t: Throwable =>
          EitherT.fromEither[Future](pf(t))
      }

    /**
      * Handle any error from this EitherT's Future (if failed) by mapping them to the EitherT's left value.
      *
      * @see [[recoverWithFlat]] for handling only certain errors
      *
      * @see [[handleErrorLeft]] for mapping to the EitherT's left value
      */
    def handleErrorLeft(pf: PartialFunction[Throwable, A]): EitherT[Future, A, B] =
      me.handleErrorWith[B](et) { t =>
        EitherT.fromEither[Future](Left[A, B](pf(t)))
      }

    /**
      * Handle any error from this EitherT's Future (if failed) by mapping them to the EitherT's value.
      *
      * @see [[recoverWithFlat]] for handling only certain errors
      *
      * @see [[handleErrorLeft]] for mapping to the EitherT's left value
      */
    def handleErrorWithFlat(pf: PartialFunction[Throwable, Either[A, B]]): EitherT[Future, A, B] =
      me.handleErrorWith[B](et) { t =>
        EitherT.fromEither[Future](pf(t))
      }
  }
}
```

I thought that these might be my first contribution to cats, but after several hours of navigating the library's layout I realized the modifications would be non trivial and I don't have the knowledge level yet to submit them in a manner that *wouldn't* require significant work from other project contributors.

I may try again once I better understand the cats library structure.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a generalized version of your `EitherTUtils`:

```
import cats.data.EitherT

object EitherTUtils {

  implicit class EitherTRecoverErrors[F[_], A, B, E](et: EitherT[F, A, B])(implicit me: MonadError[F, E]) {
    type FE[X] = EitherT[F, A, X]
    implicit val ME: MonadError[FE, E] = implicitly

    def recoverLeft(pf: PartialFunction[E, A]): EitherT[F, A, B] =
      ME.recoverWith(et)(pf.andThen(EitherT.leftT(_)))

    def recoverWithFlat(pf: PartialFunction[E, Either[A, B]]): EitherT[F, A, B] =
      ME.recoverWith(et)(pf.andThen(EitherT.fromEither(_)))

    def handleErrorLeft(f: E => A): EitherT[F, A, B] =
      ME.handleErrorWith(et)(f.andThen(EitherT.leftT(_)))

    def handleErrorWithFlat(f: E => Either[A, B]): EitherT[F, A, B] =
      ME.handleErrorWith(et)(f.andThen(EitherT.fromEither(_)))
  }

}

object Usage {
  import EitherTUtils._
  import cats.implicits._

  import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

  val e: EitherT[Future, String, Int] = EitherT.liftF(Future.failed(new RuntimeException)).recoverLeft {
    case e: IllegalStateException =>
      e.getMessage
  }

}
```

I agree cats could make it easier to work with "failed" EitherTs, hopefully we see something like this in future versions.