# Transform Future[A] to Future[Try[A]] or EitherT[Future, Throwable, A]

Tags: scala, scala-cats

How can I transform a `Future[A]` that might succeed or fail into a `EitherT[Future, Throwable, A]` or a `Future[Try[A]]`.

```scala
future.transform(result => Success(result))
EitherT(future.transform(result => Success(result.toEither)))
```

Are there methods in the standard library or within Cats that achieve the above transformation?

Comment: Is `future.transform(Success(_))` not good? It is very simple and why do you need another library to do that?

Comment: I've expected Cats to have some utility function that simplified further processing. Right now I have for instance much code like this `OptionT(future.transform(result => Success(result.toOption))))`

Comment: @texasbruce I've clarified the question. This is more specific what I expected, The question was initially asked a bit unfavorably.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`attemptT`](https://github.com/typelevel/cats/blob/584e82473dbe409d6d0e7704494e78f39ca2bdbf/core/src/main/scala/cats/ApplicativeError.scala#L78) of `ApplicativeError` can convert `Future[A]` to `EitherT[Future, Throwable, A]`, for example

```
import cats.data.EitherT
import cats.implicits._

val f: Future[A] = ???
val v: EitherT[Future, Throwable, A] = f.attemptT
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/63746823/5205022

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez No, I think if you want to actually work with `Throwable` value within `Left`, then something like `EitherT(f.attempt)` might work.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Please see edited answer.

Comment: @Aki you may want to see the edited answer too.